# How to override Gyroscope and accelerometer sensors on android device

Tags: javascript, python, typescript

I created health tracking app for my school project. But I have faced a problem while testing the movements. I have to test them physically. But is there any way to overide my mobile device sensors to that always ditect walking or running random directins while phone is on the table? In this synario all applications that are using those sensors should take the overided data to the app.

I have tried to semulated data with "AURELION" but it didn't succed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.